# Gitlab CI monorepo with submodules

Tags: next.js, gitlab-ci, git-submodules, monorepo

I have such project structure:

```
/
  /apps/
          frontend_1 [git submodule]
          frontend_2 [git submodule]
  /modules/
          ui-components [git submodule]
```

How can i implement functionality of deploy, when i need to build frontend_1 (branch main) with ui-components (branch release/v1) and frontend_2 (branch main) with ui-components (branch release/v2)